# Flutter gives errors when using TextField

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

This is the error: `Could not load source 'dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart': <source not available>.` I will use a TextField in a certain file and it will open up errors_patch.dart file that contains the error that I wrote above.

Code:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class EditNoteHeader extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditNoteHeader({super.key});

  @override
  State<EditNoteHeader> createState() => _EditNoteHeaderState();
}

class _EditNoteHeaderState extends State<EditNoteHeader> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
        child: ColoredBox(
          color: const Color(0xFF656565),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                IntrinsicHeight(
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: const [
                          TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "New Text",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include an image that you're are trying get?

Comment: would also be great to provide the output of debug sidebar with variables.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your `Textfield` inside `SizedBox` or `Container` Widget

```
    SizedBox(
            width: 300,
            height: 60,
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "New Text",
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you like to have `IntrinsicWidth` instead of `IntrinsicHeight` on `TextField`.

```dart
IntrinsicWidth(
  child: TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: "New Text",
    ),
  ),
),
```

If you need more control about sizing, you can use `LayoutBuilder` with `SizedBox(width:x` for row case.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when an error has happened and VS code or any IDE wants to display the source code however its not avaiilable in the SDK.To find out what is causing the error try to use the call stack view if using vs code to the top and take a look at the exception popup shown.